# How to fill/eliminate white spaces in a PDF in node.js?

Tags: node.js, pdf, phantomjs

Is it possible to recognize blank spots/free space in a PDF file and fill them with SVG, JPEG or PNG images with https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf?

Comment: You mean whitespace ascii characters exclusively? And which library are you using, libkit? Also what sort of images do you want to fill them in with?

Comment: I mean blank spots on a page. I search a library to do this, so actually no library is used. I want to fill this blank spots with any sort of images, e.g. JPGs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found out how to get the free space if it is at the end of the page together with PhantomJS:

```
height = totalPageHeight - element.offsetTop - bottomMargin
```